# Convertir json a un objeto serializado

Tags: java, android, kotlin, serialización

El problema que tengo es que recibo un modelo de datos de un servicio en formato json. Este modelo no se puede modificar en el lado del servidor. El problema es que unos campos de ese modelo no son consistentes.

Ando utilizando un modelo de datos en kotlin de la siguiente forma:

```
data class ResumenModel(
        @SerializedName("fGestiones") val fGestiones: FechaGestionModel? = null,
        @SerializedName("gestiones") val gestiones: List<GestionModel>? = null,
)

 class GestionModel (
        @SerializedName("ID") val ID: String? = "",
        @SerializedName("noCtes") val noCtes: String? = "",
        @SerializedName("detalles") val detalles: List<DetalleModel>? = null

)
```

El problema es con `gestiones` en  `ResumenModel`. En algunas peticiones, `gestiones` es un arreglo de `GestionModel` y en otras peticiones, el servicio responde con un objeto de `GestionModel`. Entonces al utilizar Gson para crear el objeto, no lo puede hacer ya que no puede castear el objeto a arrayList o viceversa.

Se que esta funcionando bien por que cuando ignoro `gestiones` en `ResumenModel`, `fGestiones` si se rellena correctamente (y es otro modelo de datos pero sencillo con variables primitivas)

Comment: Pues en sí el response del json que te esta enviando no esta bien estructurado no?, lo que deberia ser si es que te reponde con un arreglo, pues que de igual forma siempre te regrese un arreglo aunque tenga solo un objeto, porque me imagino que tu servicio reponse un arreglo de objetos de tipo Gestion model

Comment: @MiguelOsorio Si, exacto, ya hablamos con los compañeros que se encargan del servicio y no es posible hacer el cambio =(